# Run Visual Studio 2013 unit test without installing visual studio on server

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, batch-file, visual-studio-2013, vstesthost

I'm trying to run my unit test created via Visual Studio 2013 on my staging server.

I don't want to install Visual Studio there, not the Test Agent so I found a way to run them by copying some of the DLLs and EXEs needed.

Yes, I know it is a hack but I prefer this solution instead of the Test Agent to keep the staging environment completely clean.

Anyway, the test are correctly done, except for the fact that the vstest.discoveryengine.exe crashes with the following error:

```
failed to initialize client proxy: could not connect to vstest.discoveryengine.exe
```

Note: this crash doesn't prevent the successful completion of the tests, just an annoying popup to close any time by hand...

I tried to run my batch script as Administrator but no luck.

Have you got any hint on how to prevent vstest.discoveryengine.exe from starting or listing the existent tests?

Thank you very much

Best

cghersi

Comment: what test framework you use ? MSTest?

Comment: we are using vstest.console, in a VS 2013-like environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by manually copying some other DLLs in my folder.

Perhaps someone is interested in my same scenario, so I prepared the complete solution here:

http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/59304/How-to-run-unit-tests-created-with-MS-Vi

It perfectly works for me, and my staging environment is still perfectly clean!

Let me know if it works for you guys.

Thank you